# Use a split function in every row of one column of a data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a rather big pandas data frame (more than 1 million rows) with columns containing either strings or numbers. Now I would like to split the strings in one column before the expression "is applied".

An example to explain what I mean:

What I have:

```
a    b    description
2    4    method A is applied
10   5    titration is applied
3    1    computation is applied
```

What I am looking for:

```
 a    b    description
 2    4    method A 
 10   5    titration 
 3    1    computation
```

I tried the following,

```
df.description = df.description.str.split('is applied')[0]
```

But this didn't bring the desired result.

Any ideas how to do it? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close, need `str[0]`:

```
df.description = df.description.str.split(' is applied').str[0]
```

Alternative solution:

```
df.description = df.description.str.extract('(.*)\s+is applied')
```

---

```
print (df)
    a  b  description
0   2  4     method A
1  10  5    titration
2   3  1  computation
```

But for better performance use `list comprehension`:

```
df.description = [x.split(' is applied')[0] for x in df.description]
```

Comment: The solution with list comprehension is perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `replace`

```
df.description = df.description.str.replace(' is applied','')
df
    a  b  description
0   2  4     method A
1  10  5    titration
2   3  1  computation
```